# issue with Custom Error Pages using .htaccess

Tags: html, .htaccess

I am trying to Custom Error Pages using .htaccess. in this folder:`/home/tamp/public_html/sandbox/test`, I put .htaccess file, and inside i put this line: 
`ErrorDocument 404 /home/tamp/public_html/sandbox/test/error.html`,
and then in frontend, I did a test, I open `mysite/sandbox/test/te.php(te.php does not exist)`, but it still shows the default error page: `The requested URL /test/tes.php was not found on this server`. My error.html did not show up.
So what may go wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with ErrorDocument you can't use full file-system path:

> URLs can begin with a slash (/) for local web-paths (relative to the
>   DocumentRoot), or be a full URL which the client can resolve.

so assuming that your website root folder is sandbox:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /test/error.html
```